# change color of parent in the expandableList

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to change the background color of the parent in an ExpandableList, in my mainActivity.

the background color will be changed in some particular parent.

How can i do this ?

Comment: You want to change the background of the ExpandableList or its parent?

Comment: the color of the group item

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant but if you want to set the parent background color just add this to it's xml:
`android:background = "@color/green"`

If you meant only for the ExpendableList items, add the above line to their layout.

You can see an example here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/